# Matlab subtracting matrix elements

Tags: matlab, matrix, element

so i have this matrix

data =

```
 1
 3
 4
 3
 5
 2
 5
```

i need to get new data by subtracting the element
like this

```
data2-data1
data3-data2
data4-data3
data5-data4
data6-data5
data7-data4
...
datan-data(n-1)
```

so from that data the output should be
im =

```
 2
 1
-1
 2
-3
 3
```

i still trying to manipulate this code but got an error

```
clc
data=[1;3;4;3;5;2;5]
cnt=size(data,1)

for i=1:cnt;
    im=(data(i)-(data(i-1)));
end
im
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`diff` does what you want.

```
diff(data)
```

BUT if you want to continue with your approach, I imagine the error you get is related to `data(i-1)` cannot be defined when `i = 1`. Your loop should be `2:cnt`.

Another method would be `data(2:end) - data(1:end-1)`

Comment: can you get the same answer without using diff ? just trying to not using any function, but that exactly answering my question actually

Comment: I edited my answer. Although I don't know for certain what the error you came across was.

Comment: oh change the loop do the same as diff, thank you so much